# primefaces p:message outside the components form

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.2.

I'm using Facelets for templating, and I've built a 3-column layout:

Left column - mainContent column - Right column. Each column got it's own template xhtml file with ui:composition which I insert in a mainTemplate.

In the mainContent column I've got a info-button (p:commandButton):

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
<p:commandButton id="infoButton" value="Info" actionListener="#{faceletsAttachment.addInfo}"/> 
</h:form>
```

But I want the info to show in the right column, with a

```
<h:form id="rightColumnForm">
<p:message for="infoButton">
</h:form>
```

This obviously does not work, because  does not find the infoButton. Any idea how I can make this work? I tried

```
<p:message for="mainForm:infoButton">
```

too, but no cigar.

The reason I want to use a p:message is that I want the message to position itself on the y-position the infoButton has. If you got an alternative solution to how I can do this, I would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding messages manually from server side you can do the following

`<p:message id="myInfoButton" for="myInfoButton" />`

and send messages from server to `myInfoButton` like this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance.addMessage("myInfoButton ", new FacesMessage("My Message", "Some Text goes here..."));
```

also add `:rightColumnForm` id to update of the `<p:commandButton id="infoButton"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I didn't get this to work:
In my backingbean: 

    public void addInfo(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myInfoButton", new FacesMessage("My Message", "Some Text goes here..."));  
  }  

And the 

<p:message id="myInfoButton" for="myInfoButton" />

inside my form. No message appeared when i pressed the commandButton. Also I'm not sure how this will align the message in the correct y-position?

Comment: edited , you need to update the rightColumnForm form so it will re render the view...

Comment: Yes, that takes me one step closer, but it is important that the message is displayed in the same y-position as the commandButton..

Comment: well the y-position is more a design question... its being rendered to span element i think (the h:message) so you can "play" with css , absolute position maybe... open your browser dev tools (chrome F12 is great) and start aligning the elements... (It looks like your logical part of the question was solved...)

Comment: This needs to be generic, since the logic will be reused several places in the application, and the infobutton will not have the same y-position. I think I will have to play with javascript instead. But close enough. Thank you for the help!